# What changes do Windows-10 updates make?

Tags: windows-10

Having installed Windows 10, I now have updates applied regularly.  These are linked to a knowledge base articles.  However, these KB references don't tell me much about what the updates actually change.  The most recent refers to KB3081444, which just says "...improvements in the functionality of Windows 10".  Is there anywhere that MS publishes information about the changes made?  What are the "improvements".  (I think the last change involved an update to the kernel - non-trivial stuff.)

Comment: Your guess is good as anyone's, what information is shared in a knowledge article, is changing.

Comment: [Microsoft Stance on detail changes dealing with Cumulative Updates (CU)](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/212724-microsoft-kills-patch-notes-will-no-longer-explain-most-windows-10-updates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft have now relented.  They are publishing information here http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/update-history-windows-10